# Split data into train and validation in keras when path to images are loaded

Tags: python, keras

Assuming I have a list of paths called `a`. Each element links to an image in a dataset, that was not split up yet into training and validation. I can divide the list `a` of course into a list `x` and a list `y` which will represent the training and the validation paths respectively.

Is it possible to either feed the split up paths into a Keras model or to let Keras split up the list by itself?

I onl y ofund the ImageDataGenerator which I do not need, since the dataset I use is already augmented, and everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the validation_split optional argument in model.fit. It splits the data provided automatically in training and validation, taking as validation data the last percentage of samples.
https://keras.io/models/sequential/
https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-is-the-validation-split-computed